# $\lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} {^{b}a} \in \mathbb{Q}_p$ for any $a \in \mathbb{Z}^+$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, open-problems, p-adic-analysis, p-adic-numbers, tetration

$\newcommand\tetra[2]{{^{#1}{#2}}}$In a recent discussion on the Tetration Forum (see https://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=1703&page=2), it has been pointed out how my results on the constancy of the "congruence speed" of the integer tetration $\tetra b a$ (a peculiar property of hyper-$4$ described in [The congruence speed formula](https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.02622)), would imply that $\lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} \tetra b a$ is always an element of the set $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

At the time, I did not fully realize the power of this breakthrough, since my original goal was only to find a function $V(a) : \mathbb{Z}^+-\{M\} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^+$, where $M = \{a : a \not\equiv 0 \pmod {10} \land a \neq 1\}$, but after a little search, I have seen that this is a general open problem, explicitly solved only for a few cases (since 1953, for $a:=2$). Furthermore, I have not managed to find any proof that even $\lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} \tetra b 6$ is a rational $p$-adic number (or rather an irrational one, disproving the aforementioned claim).

Now, my first concern is if I am wrong and $\lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} \tetra b 6$ has already been proven to be an element of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (or not), while my general request here is to know more about the implications of Equation 16 on page 15 of [Ripà and Onnis - Number of stable digits of any integer tetration](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.07956) on the above mentioned general open problem (and related topics).

Comment: For those wishing to work on this without knowledge of tetration:  Does the sequence $$6,\quad 6^6,\quad,6^{6^6},\cdots$$converge in the $p$-adic integers?  That is: is this sequnce eventually constant mod $p$ and mod $p^2$ and mod $p^3$ and so on?  Here $p$ is a prime, and perhaps the answer varies with $p$.

Comment: I tried $p=5$, and found that it seems to converge to a certain $5$-adic number $$1+1\cdot 5+ 1\cdot 5^2+ 4\cdot 5^3+ 1\cdot 5^4+ 1\cdot 5^5+ 3\cdot 5^6+ 4\cdot 5^7+ 4\cdot 5^8+ 2\cdot 5^9+\dots$$

Comment: According to ChatGPT the sequence $a(n) = {^{n}6}$ does not converge to any element of $\mathbb{Z}_5$. Moreover, in general, he/it says that "the sequence grows so quickly that it 'escapes' to infinity in the p-adic metric for any prime $p$".
Thus, it would follow that $a(n) = {^{n}6}$ does not converge in the $p$-adic integers, but there is more... he/it also argues that "the sequence ${^{n}6}$ does not converge in the $p$-adic rationals for any prime $p$". I am quite afraid of this shocking outcome from an AI.

Comment: @Marco ChatGPT is stupid at math. Ignore anything it says.

Comment: Ahahhahaha, I know... but I wonder how it can produce so much text/nonsense without a sufficient knowledge of the given subject. Sorry for the not-math digression.

Comment: If $a \equiv 1\bmod p$ for $p \not= 2$ and $a \equiv 1\bmod 4$ for $p = 2$, we have $|a^m -a^n|_p = |a-1|_p|m-n|_p$ for $m, n$ in $\mathbf Z$. So $|a^a -a|_p = |a-1|_p|a-1|_p = |a-1|_p^2$, $|a^{a^a}- a^a|_p = |a-1|_p|a^a- a|_p = |a-1|_p^3$, and in general $|^{b}a-\, ^{b-1}a|_p = |a-1|_p^{b}$. So $|^{b}a -\, ^{b-1}a|_p \to 0$ as $b \to \infty$. In the $p$-adics, a sequence $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy if and only if it is "consecutively Cauchy" (meaning $|x_n - x_{n-1}|_p \to 0$.  So $\{^b{a}\}_{b \geq 0}$ has a limit for $a \in 1 + p\mathbf Z_p$ if $p\not=2 $ and for $a\in 1 + 4\mathbf Z_2$ if $p = 2$.

Comment: So is the question really about convergence, or whether the limit is a rational number?

Comment: I think a misunderstanding has occurred, since in the paper I use "constant congruence speed" referring to a peculiar property of tetration... so I was asking a different question, my bad for not having clearly specified this fact.
Basically, by assuming radix-10, I have proven that the number of stable/frozen digitis of any integer tetration base $a \geq 0 : a$ is not a multiple of $10$, for any unitary increment of the hyperexponent, only depends on $a$ if $b$ is sufficiently large (as a sufficient but not necessary HP you can assume $b \geq a + 1$.

Comment: Thus, my question is about "whether the limit is a rational number" in p-adics.

Comment: I still have no idea what the actual question is. Please add more details to make it a self-contained precise mathematical question (or maybe ask a separate one, given that the question whether the limit exists in $\mathbf Q_p$ has been answered below). I do not see the link between speed of convergence and whether the limit is in $\mathbf Q \cap \mathbf Z_p$. Or do you mean something else by 'rational'?

Comment: Thank you, I definitely would have written the thread more carefully. Perhaps it would be better to write a separate topic, voting the answer as a final answer, since the original question has been closed. Anyway, my point was that, since from my research it follows that, for every prime number $p$, $\lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} {^{b}a}$ belongs to $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for any integer $a$, we could use this fact to work on related open problems (I've provided that formula by using the  well-known homomorphism to move the analysis to $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$). Any further contribution is welcome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A sequence given by $x_1=a$, $x_{n+1}=a^{x_n}$, where $a$ is a positive integer, is eventually constant modulo every positive integer $T$. This is widely known.

A short proof. We induct in $T$, so assume that $T>1$ and the claim is proven for smaller numbers. Denote $T=T_1T_2$, where $T_1$ has prime divisors which divide $a$, and $T_2$ is coprime with $a$. Modulo $T_1$, obviously $x_n$ become equal to 0. Modulo $T_2$, the value of $x_n$ is determined by the remainder of $x_{n-1}$ modulo $\varphi(T_2)<T_2$, thus by induction hypothesis it is eventually constant.

I hope that this is what was asked.

Comment: Ah, I was just writing out a similar argument, but yours is even slicker.